# Permutations of a Range with Format Python3

Tags: python, format, range, permutation

I'm trying to permutations of my keys by using formats and ranges. I want my output to look like this:

```
{'00', '000', '0000': 'A1'}
{'01', '10', '001', '010', '100', '0001', '0010', '0100', '1000': 'A2'}
{'02', '20', '002', '020', '200', '0002', '0020', '0200', '2000': 'A3'}
```

The code above renders accurately if I just do ustr = [a1 % i for i in range(0, 2)] but when I do `ustr = [(a1 % i, b1 % i) for i in range(0, 2)]` it combines them and produces duplicates. I know that my `f''.join(i)` is causing the issue I just can't figure out how to get this to render the way I want it to.

```
from itertools import permutations

wd = {}

a1, b1, c1 = '%.2d', '%.3d', '%.4d'

ustr = [(a1 % i, b1 % i) for i in range(0, 3)]

d2 = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(ustr)))}

wd.update(d2)
for k, v in wd.items():
    perms = [f''.join(i) for i in list(sorted(set(permutations(k))))]
    print(perms)
```

Comment: What does your current output look like?

Comment: ['000000', '000000']
['000101', '010001']

Comment: And your output, what data type is that supposed to be? Do you mean for it to be a dictionary with `A1` `A2` `A3` as the keys and a list of the other numbers as the value?

Comment: I tried the following:                                                                 ustr = [a1 % i for i in range(0, 2)]
d2 = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(permutations(ustr))))}
print(d2)                                                                                           Output: {('00', '01'): 'A1', ('01', '00'): 'A2'                                                                          So I'm closer but not quite there yet.

Comment: Right now I want A1, A2, A3 to be the values and the keys to be the numbers. I'll reverse it if I need to but I plan on going from range(0,10)

Comment: So you want one output dictionary with keys for each result and the value to be the A1, A2, or A3?

Comment: yes so keys = {'00', '000', '0000':'A1'}, {'01', '10', '001', '010', '100':'A2'}, {'02', '20', '002', '020', '200':'A3'} all the numbers are the keys and the A1, A2, A3 is the value so all those numbers == one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the desired string (printing each row).

Note that your desired output does not conform to any python data structure, so I am assuming it must be a string.

```
from itertools import chain

max_i = 3  # A1, A2, A3, ...
max_j = 4  # '01', '001', '0001'
d = {}
for i in range(1, max_i + 1):
    key = f'A{i}'
    numbers = list('0' * n + str(i) for n in range(1, max_j))
    perms = [sorted(set(permutations(number_str, len(number_str)))) 
             for number_str in numbers]
    tups = (''.join(p) for p in chain.from_iterable(perms))
    k = ", ".join(f"'{t}'" for t in tups) 
    print(f"{{{k}: 'A{i}'}}")
# Output
{'00', '000', '0000': 'A1'}
{'01', '10', '001', '010', '100', '0001', '0010', '0100', '1000': 'A2'}
{'02', '20', '002', '020', '200', '0002', '0020', '0200', '2000': 'A3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below will do what you are wanting to do. To use it just do `fun(n)` where `n` is the max of the range.

```py
def fun(n):
    out = {}
    for q in range(0,5):                                 # this generates the multi-length outputs
        for i in range(0, n):                            # go through max length of original range
            y = [0 for x in range(0, q - len(str(i)))]   # this adds needed 0's
            y.append(i)                                  # add current i back in
            for w in list(set(permutations(y))):         # get the permutations
                r = ''.join([str(i) for i in y])         # turn them into strings
                out[r] = 'A' + str(i + 1)                # put them into dictionary with appropriate value of "A"
    return out
```

example:

```py
>>> x = fun(2)
>>> print(x)
{'0': 'A1', '1': 'A2', '00': 'A1', '01': 'A2', '000': 'A1', '001': 'A2', '0000': 'A1', '0001': 'A2'}
```